# How to choose a destination spreadsheet of copied data based on spreadsheet name

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have two tables. Table 1 is a large table with 7 columns. In this table, C2:C has unique ID numbers of people. Table 2 is a smaller table with the names of all people in K3:K and the unique ID on J3:J.  Table 2 only has 2 columns, the IDs and the Name.  So, All IDs in C2:C exists in K3:K. All the names in K3:K are also the names of sheets in the same worksheet. So what I'm trying to do is:

Loop through the IDs in table 1 (large table) with the IDs in table 2 (small table). If the IDs are the same, then I will copy the whole row in table 1 into my destination sheet. To choose my destination sheet, I check the cell adjacent to the identified ID in table 2 and choose the sheet whose name is the same.

I hope i explained that decently. My problem it's copying things in every 10 intervals. So it copies the 10th row, then the 20th, then the 30th... and I'm confused how to even approach figuring out where I went wrong because I don't understand why it's in 10 interverals and why it's choosing the sheets that its choosing.

If it helps, link to the sheet is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1522hM3mO9AdaTpiS2oI1IK3wwwFXbOz1qHxcMrRzASY/edit?usp=sharing

```
function copystuff() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName();
var currentS = ss.getSheetByName(key);
var sheetNameArray = [];

sheetNameArray = sheets.map(function(sheet){  //  puts sheet names into an array
  return [sheet.getName()];
                           });
var name_master = currentS.getRange("K3:K").getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!=''); //key name
var enno_master = currentS.getRange("J3:J").getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!=''); //key ID
var enno_all = currentS.getRange("C2:C").getValues().flat().filter(r=>r!=''); // number of big table

for (x = 0; x< enno_master.length; x++){ //to loop through the key number
for (y = 0; y < enno_all.length; y++){  // to loop through the numbers of big table
    if(enno_master[x]==enno_all[y]){ // if ID in column C = name in column J
     for(z = 0; z < sheetNameArray.length; z++){ //looping through my sheets
        if(name_master[x] == sheetNameArray[[z]]){ //if name in column K, which is of the same row as the key number

          var copyrange = currentS.getRange("A"+y+2+":G"+y+2).getValues(); //y is the row in table 1 where the IDs are the same. 
          var destfile = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[[z]]); //copying to sheet Z. 
          destfile.getRange(destfile.getLastRow()+1,1,1,7).setValues(copyrange); //paste
          

        }
} 
}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that makes it easy is turning your small table into an object so that when the object is given the number in column 3 of the big table it returns the actual sheet object.  The array `pA` in object `sht` provides you with the ability to check using `indexOf()` if the Sheet actually exists in the object without having to use `hasOwnProperty()`.

```
function copyStuff() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const objvs = sh.getRange(3,10,getColumnHeight(10,sh,ss)-2,2).getValues();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,7).getValues();
  let sht = {pA:[]};
  objvs.forEach(r => {sht[r[0]]=ss.getSheetByName(r[1]); sht.pA.push(r[0])});//This creates an object which correlates enNo to a sheet making it possible to greatly simplify your code.
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(~sht.pA.indexOf(r[2])) {//this determines if the sheet is defined in sht object if it is then you can do a copy because the sheet exists
      let s = sht[r[2]];
      if(s) {
        s.appendRow(r);//this appends the entire row to the next empty row at the bottom of data.  You could also use copyTo or setValues().  This is a simple approach.
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Helper function: this function is used to the the height of column `j`. It's sort of the `getLastRow()` but only for a column:

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

[~ Bitwise Not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT)

The easiest way to find information in the documentation is to use the index in it.  Especially since they just changed it all and many of us no longer know where everything is.

Comment: I test it in your account with another browser and a different account and it seems to work okay

Answer (score 0):

### SUGGESTION:

Since you want to check the large table `A:G` & then copy each table data that matches every user ID on the second table `J:K` and move those matched rows to the designated sheet named after the IDs' user names, you can refer to this sample implementation below:

```
function copystuff() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var main =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNameArray = sheets.map(function(sheet){
  return [sheet.getName()]});
  var lastRowK = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow(),11).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow(); //Get the last row of column K on any worksheet
  var user = main.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[0]).getRange("J3:K"+lastRowK).getValues();
  var tableData = main.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[0]).getRange("A2:G"+main.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues();
  var container = [];

  for(x=0; x<user.length; x++){ //Loop every user from the second table
    for(y=0; y<tableData.length; y++){ //loop through the large table data
      if(tableData[y][2] == user[x][0]){ //check each user's ID if it has any matches on the user ID from the large table data
        container.push(tableData[y]); //any matched row data from the large table will be placed temporarily on this container
      }
    }
    if(container.length != 0){
      Logger.log("User "+user[x][1]+ " with ID *"+ user[x][0] +"* has these data:\n"+container);
      main.getSheetByName(user[x][1]).getRange(1,1,container.length,7).setValues(container);
    }
    container = []; //clean container for the next user
  }
}
```

> This script will get all table data and place them into an array variables `user` & `tableData` where it will be checked and processed to make the script run faster instead of live processing the sheet rows.

### Sample Result:

> After running the script, here are some of the results:

**User name `RJ` with ID of `42`:**

[image]

**User name `May` with ID of `7`:**

[image]

**User name `Angelo` with ID of `25`:**

[image]

### Here's the Log Results for review:

[image]